# Django ModelForm is not displaying in Template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a form that enables the user to input his email, whenever a product is out of stock, through a bootstrap modal.

However, the form **{{ form.as_p }}** is not showing on the template (see picture below).

**Furthermore**, I'm not sure how to pass in the Product.id and Product.name so that its visible along with the email, whenever a user clicks submit, on the Django Admin side?

[image]

models.py

```
class ReminderEmail(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    remindemail = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import ReminderEmail

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReminderEmail
        fields = [
            'remindemail'
        ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
import datetime

from .models import *
from .forms import *

def email_remind_view(request):
    form = EmailForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    
    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, "store.html", context)
```

store.html

```
<div id="stockModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                <div id="modalheader" class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">This product is Out of Stock</h5>
                </div>
                <div id="modalbody" class="modal-body">
                    <p>Enter your email to be reminded whenever this product goes back in stock.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!-- <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name.."> -->
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input id="submitEmail" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit Email">
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="{{product.image.url}}">
        <div class="box-element product">
            <h6><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h6>
            <h7>{{product.quantity}} left</h7>
            <!-- <h7 class="hidden" id="out-of-stock">Notify When Available</h7> -->
            <div id="content"></div>
            <hr>
            <button id="ATC" data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add"
                class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
            <button id="Remind" data-product={{product.id}} class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn hidden">Notify Me
                When
                Available</button>
            <!-- <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">View</a> -->
            <h4 id="price" style="display: inline-block; float: right">${{product.price|floatformat:2}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.store, name="store"),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name="cart"),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),

    path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name="update_item"),
    path('process_order/', views.processOrder, name="process_order"),

    path('email/', views.email_remind_view, name="email_remind_view"),
]
```

Tested code in store.html

```
<form method="POST"></form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input id="submitEmail" type="submit" value="Submit Email">
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `forms.py`, you missing import `models`:

```
from .models import models, ReminderEmail
```

2. If you want pass `Product.id` and `Product.name` you need declare them in your `forms.py` and hide them in your html template:

```
from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReminderEmail
        fields = ('remindemail', 'product',)
        widgets = {
             'product': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't solve my problem, the input field still doesn't appear on the template. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you missing `method='post'` and `csrf_token` for form.

Comment: Did you check css or js? Maybe parent div hide it.

Comment: I added <form method="post"> and {% csrf_token %} before {{ form }} but it still doesn't work. Also checked CSS and nothing seems to hide it...

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` model after you create or update it?

Comment: I did that, yes. Could it be something to do with the position of the <form>?

Comment: In your `forms.py`, try add `from .models import models, ReminderEmail`. I think you missing import `models`

Comment: I also tried that but it does not change anything. I had `from .models import *`

Comment: In your `forms.py`, not `views.py`

Comment: Yes, I did so. Nothing appears.

Comment: Please save `forms.py` file and try run `python manage.py runserver` again. If it still doesn't work, you can try bring `{{ form }}` outside `<div id="stockModal"></div>`, I think maybe it's a reason.

Comment: Hi! I tried bringing the form out of the div and that didn't work either... Very odd. I must be missing something

Comment: Or you can create a new form get same model or difference model to test.

Comment: Hi Simbeul! You excess a tag `</form>` in `<form method="POST"></form>`, already have tag `</form>` bellow. And don't forget add `from models import models, ReminderEmail` in your `forms.py`.